# Eclipse Platform Plug-in Developer Guide help section missing

Tags: eclipse

I have just started using the Eclipse IDE. I downloaded version 4.7.0 (Oxygen) of the "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers" zipped archive.

I am now looking for the "Platform Plug-in Developer Guide" help section, but it is missing. How do I get that help section into my Eclipse for offline viewing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ***Help > Install New Software...***, in ***Work with*** choose ***--All Available Sites--***, select ***Eclipse Plugin Development Tools > Eclipse PDE Plug-in Developer Resources*** and click ***Next >***.

Note, the *Eclipse **Java EE** IDE for Web Developers* package **does not contain** the [Plug-in Development Environment (**PDE**)](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/). If you want to install not only the documentation but also PDE, select *Eclipse Plugin Development Tools* instead.